# Regex Find Spaces between single qoutes and replace with underscore

Tags: regex, replace, find

I have a database table that I have exported. I need to replace the image file name with a space and would like to use notepad++ and regex to do so. I have:

```
'data/green tea powder.jpg'
'data/prod_img/lumina herbal shampoo.JPG'
'data/ALL GREEN HERBS.jpeg'
'data/prod_img/PSORIASIS KIT (640x530) (2).jpg'
```

and need to make them look like this:

```
'data/green_tea_powder.jpg'
'data/prod_img/lumina_herbal_shampoo.JPG'
'data/ALL_GREEN_HERBS.jpeg'
'data/prod_img/PSORIASIS_KIT_(640x530)_(2).jpg'
```

I just want to change the spaces between the quotes (I don't want to change the capitalization). To be more specific I would like to replace any and all spaces between 'data/ and ' because there are other spaces between quotes in the DB, for example:

```
'data/ REPLACE ANY SPACE HERE '
```

I found this:

```
\s(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

but there are other places where there are spaces between quotes so I'd like to search for `data/` in the beging and not just a single quote but I can't figure out how. I tried `\s(?!(?:[^'data\/]*'[^']*')*[^']*$)` but it didn't work and I am not familiar enough with regex to make it do so.

An example of a full line from the database is:

```
(712, 'GRTE-P', '', 'data/green tea powder.jpg', '2014-03-12 22:52:03'),
```

I don't want to replace the spaces in the time and data stamp at the end of the line, just the image file names.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a `\G` based pattern to ensure that matches are contiguous.

search: `(?:\G(?!^)|'data/)[^' ]*\K[ ]`
replace: `_`

The first match uses the second branch of the alternation, then the next matches are contiguous and use the first branch.

Comment: Thanks but that is only picking up 13 matches on what should be a few hundred and not the spaces, for example in this: `(562, '', 'data/dark tablet.jpg','2014-01-23 19:23:44'),` I get `'data/dark` as a match when I just need the space between dark and tablet. This one doesn't match anything: `(575, '', 'data/ALL GREEN HERBS.jpeg', '2014-02-06 19:24:39'),` when I want to get the spaces between `ALL GREEN HERBS`.

Comment: This has gotten me a little closer: `\s(?:\G(?!^)|data/)[^']*` What this does is return everything from the first space after `'data/` to the next quote. Now I need a way to select spaces only. Also it doesn't capture if I have a slight variation on the file structure `'data/prod_img/Samshamani 240 tablets.jpg'` I would need something that would capture if I had '/prod_img/' in there as well.

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)|data/)[^']*` this gets everything between the quotes but I need to replace just the spaces.

Comment: @MattM: The pattern has been tested on notepad++ and works. Be sure to have an up-to-date version. You can see a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/o2PFSv/1

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why it didn't work but updated and replaced everything correctly, you rock!

Comment: @MattM: I think you had missed the space in the character class:`[^' ]`